# GreenPlum. Как создать ограничения на внешний ключ

Tags: база-данных

Есть 2 таблицы:
table2:

```
CREATE TABLE public.table2 (
    b serial4 NOT NULL,
    b1 varchar NULL,
    CONSTRAINT table2_pk PRIMARY KEY (b)
);
```

table1:

```
CREATE TABLE public.table1 (
    a serial4 NOT NULL,
    b int4 NULL,
    d varchar NULL,
    CONSTRAINT table1_pk PRIMARY KEY (a),
    CONSTRAINT table1_fk FOREIGN KEY (b) REFERENCES public.table2(b)
);
```

Содержание таблицы table2
[image: Содержание таблицы table2]

Содержание таблицы table1
[image: Содержание таблицы table1]

При выполнении вставки в таблицу table1:

```
INSERT INTO public.table1
(a, b, d)
VALUES(nextval('table1_a_seq'::regclass), 3, 'Пример 3');
```

Ошибки не вызывает и это в Greenplum нормально.
Вопрос:
Как реализовать механизм контроля существования значений внешних ключей? Чтобы при выполнении вышеприведенной вставки база сообщала, что ключ в таблице table2 не найден.

Comment: Можно добавить констреин на уникальность!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CREATE TABLE](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Greenplum/7/greenplum-database/ref_guide-sql_commands-CREATE_TABLE.html?hWord=N4IghgNiBcIGYHsBOBTAlgcwHYAIDWKAniAL5A)

> Greenplum accepts referential integrity constraints but does not enforce them.

[SET CONSTRAINTS](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Greenplum/7/greenplum-database/ref_guide-sql_commands-SET_CONSTRAINTS.html?hWord=N4IghgNiBcIGYHsBOBTAlgcwHYAIDWKAniAL5A)

> Referential integrity syntax (foreign key constraints) is accepted but not enforced.

---

> Как реализовать механизм контроля существования значений внешних ключей?

Ну, может, попробовать решить проблему экстенсивно? долой запросы, даёшь процедуры. А уж в процедуре можно проверить любые мыслимые условия..

Comment: Это конечно хорошо, если таблиц немного, а если их пара сотен.

Comment: @Twanger Если внешние ключи критичны - то, может, есть смысл признать, что выбор СУБД был ошибочен, и сменить её?